# Simple html dom divide html into chunks with table as a delimiter

Tags: html, simple-html-dom, scrape

I have to scrape data from a webpage. Problem is that content is not contained into divs or any other tag. The only element I found that separates the chuncks of data I need is the following table. It doesn't have id nor class but it does contain an image only found in that table.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr> 
    <td width="97%" height="25"> 
      <hr size="2" noshade color="7B4023">
    </td>
    <td width="3%" height="25">
    <img src="../../images/term.gif" width="20" height="20"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Can you think of any way of spliting html into chunks using that table as a delimiter?
Thanks in advance.
Sebastián

Answer (score 0):

For your example, after loading the webpage into a simple html dom you can use preg_split on the string $html:

```
$chunks = preg_split("/(<table )/",$html,null,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo $chunk;
}
```

I used preg_split instead of explode in order to keep the delimiter in the chunks as well.

Comment: No, I want to separate html into chunks using that table as a delimiter.

Comment: then just change 'table td' to 'table' and innertext to outertext

Comment: It's not my page. I have to scrape the content's from a webpage that I do not manage.

Comment: Yeah. Just load the webpage into a simple html dom and use above code.

Comment: I do not want the text inside the table. I need to separate html into pieces using the table as a delimiter. I already know how to extract different elements using simple html dom parser.

Comment: In that case use explode() to return the html as an array with the table as a delimiter.

Comment: Thanks @johnh10 Expling using part of the table as a delimiter worked like a charm. If you want to edit yor answer I'll accept it.